# intellij not save collapse code for jsp pages

Tags: intellij-idea

I am collapsing some parts of my jsp code but when I close and open the file, ide open it without any collapse, the collapse is working with classes but in the jsp file it is not working, how can I solve this?

for example if I collapsed tab1 div and after that I closed the page ... after that I open it again I will see tab1 div not collapsed

Comment: You mean that the collapse is working, but it doesn't save the collapsed preference? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: yes it is working but it is not saving the state ... for example I collapsed tab1 and after that I closed the page ... after that I open it again I will see tab1 not collapsed